# How do I restrict how long a user can edit a record in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, edit

I'm making a bloglike website where users can post notes and I want to restrict them to only being able to edit posts for the first 3 days after posting and I'm having trouble with it.

I have the following code in my notes controller

```
class NotesController < ApplicationController
before_filter :check_time!, only: [:edit, :update]

def edit
end

def create
end

private

def check_time!
  if @note.created_at > @note.created_at + 3.hours
    flash[:danger] = 'Out of 3 days'
    redirect_to note_path(@note)
  end
end
end
```

I have a post which is 1 day old, and for testing purposes I am using hours instead of days in the check_time! method in my code to see if it works, however it doesn't. For some reason it does work if I change from > to < however.

I'm sure I've attached a created_at timestamp to my notes using the following migration:

```
class AddTimestampsToNote < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
def change_table 
add_column(:notes, :created_at, :datetime) 
add_column(:notes, :updated_at, :datetime) 
end 
end
```

I'm really not sure why this does not work, so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code  has the following:

```
if @note.created_at > @note.created_at + 3.hours
```

This statement is never true (x !> x + 3).  Perhaps you meant:

```
Time.now > @note.created_at + 3.hours
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a custom validation instead.

```
class Note < ApplicationRecord 
  # ...
  validate :is_editable, unless: :new_record?

  private 
  def is_editable
    if @note.created_at > 3.days.ago
      errors[:created_at] = "can't be edited after 3 days."
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I think you have the condition backwards here, but otherwise this is definitely the way to do it.

Comment: Thanks @Glyoko. Fixed

Comment: I tried this but get the following error: undefined method `validate' for NotesController:Class

Comment: You add the validation to your model - not the controller.